# Realigning pointers after memory realign

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-alignment, memory-pool

I have a memory pool which is a set size and is split into segments of a given size. When I delete some data it flags the segments that data was using as free. Next time I try to allocate memory but don't have space, I realign the memory by shifting all the data down (e.g. First 2 segments are cleared, move all data down by 2 blocks). This all works fine but my issue is my pointers to that data don't change and I am not sure how I can go about doing this.

[image]

I allocate memory from my pool by returning a void* to the space in memory, lets assume my pool is the size to hold 2*sizeof(Data).

```
Data* poolTest = new(pool->GetMemory(sizeof(Data))) Data(5, 5, 5);
```

So the pool has no reference to the pointer poolTest.

So now if I do this:

```
pool->Free(poolTest);
Data* poolTest2 = new(pool->GetMemory(sizeof(Data))) Data(4, 5, 5);
Data* poolTest3 = new(pool->GetMemory(sizeof(Data))) Data(3, 5, 5);
```

The creation of poolTest3 triggers a realignment of memory and now poolTest2 points to the same address as poolTest3 and poolTest1 points to the address that poolTest2 should point to.

I might just be missing something, or my structure is screwed up but I am really stuck on this.

Comment: Why realign the memory rather than just having the allocation mechanism return the freed memory directly? Manually compacting memory on *every* allocation after free is going to kill performance (and as you note, invalidates existing pointers unless you go to quite a bit of trouble to either fix them up or have them operate through an additional layer of indirection).

Comment: It is to maximise available space. It is possible to pass in any data type, so you could pass in a struct that takes up 2.5  segments. So if I request some data that needs more than the available segments, then I realign it to make at least 3 aligned segments (if available), I don't realign every time I allocate. If I don't do this I could end up with entire segments that are wasted as I can use them.

Comment: Also I move the data using memmove on a char* which is only O(n) (n being the number of segments after the deleted segments) so it is actually quite efficient and wouldn't need to be called that often.

Comment: Typical allocators handle the wasted fragments issue by simply holding off on using them until an allocation comes in that is small enough to use it (and if a newly freed block is adjacent to another freed block, joining them). `O(n)` work where `n` is the size of any reasonably sized memory segment is a pretty high cost actually; traversing a free list is only `O(n)` in number of *blocks* on the free list (and in practice you rarely have to traverse very far), where the `memmove` is `O(n)` in terms of segment size (and average case involves moving half your data).

Comment: Now, I do see that realignment is only occurring if your fixed size heap is actually *out* of memory, so if you have a free list and you're actually reusing memory first, and only realigning if fragmentation has made all remaining memory unusable, you might not be realigning as often as I think. But it's still going to be hard to handle properly; as long as raw, unmanaged pointers are allowed, it's [basically impossible to defragment a heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17009023/364696). You need a much more sophisticated memory management system to allow it.

Comment: A thought which I will try out tomorrow is if it possible to store a references to void pointers in an array and then decrement them when I need, but no idea if this is possible or if it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rephrase your question:

**I want to move data around in memory to make room for new allocations. How to I make sure existing pointers still point to the right places?**

**You can't**, unless you keep track of all the pointers, say, by using an array, and instead of accessing your data like this:

```
*direct_ptr
```

you now have to do this:

```
*ptr_map[indirect_ptr]
```

Every time you move things around, you need to modify ptr_map accordingly.

The array should behave like a stack. You could maybe write a pointer wrapper class that increments some global/static index in the constructor and decrements it in the destructor.

It may save a little space but is quite inefficient for the computer and messy for the programmer.

If you want to do your own memory management, make sure you check out:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation

And a good overview of existing techniques:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/vm-freespace.pdf

Comment: The [LMAX disruptor](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor) may also be an alternative, They have lots of code to show why it works too.